# editing a profile based on username selected from a grid of usernames displayed on home page using jsp

Tags: jsp

I'm new to `jsp`. I have an application in which there is a home page with 3 buttons `new`, `edit`, `delete` on the top and a grid displaying the firstnames of all the records in the table `newuser`.If I select a firstname by clicking on it, I should get a page where all the fields corresponding to that username are to be retrieved from database and are to be displayed and should be editable.

Can anyone please help me out with this...

Comment: Please post your which you have tried

Comment: code for "edit" button:                                          <td style="height:20px;float:left;"><form action="values.jsp" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="Edit" value="Edit">
</form></td>
code for assigning value to radiobutton:                                                              <td style="height:20px;float:left;"><form action="values.jsp" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="Edit" value="Edit">
</form></td>

Comment: code for getting all the related fields of button fromtable:                                                               <% 
 String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname");
 System.out.println("firstname"+firstname);
  %>

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link, which contain some sample example.

http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/crud-application.shtml

http://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/

Thanks.

Comment: i tried assigning a radio button to the field "firstname" of all records and on clicking that button retrieving details and displaying.But in vain.

Comment: what ever component you use don't matter... because you are going to call onclick event of that component. have a look over the link which i specify and make modification on your code. Still if you face problem, please post your code for reference.

Comment: My files are:                                                                    Home.jsp

Comment: Thank u Hariharan for your reply....but in the second link you gave....there is link for "update" button.What I want is to get all the columns from database corresponding to the "firstname" clicked.